# ImageResizer IIS/IIS Express VirtualFolder Issues

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, imageresizer

I'm trying to set up an MVC4 website that will act as an image CDN and I can't get the VirtualFolder functionality to work in IIS or IIS Express for "raw" (unmodified) files.  If I switch the website to the built-in webserver then I can make a request for the "raw" file and it'll load.  In both cases if I use the a querystring such as ?width=300 the image is loaded correctly.

Ultimately my goal is to create my own plugin that will be loading files from a content service we have managing our dynamic content but I'm just trying to get the thing working in general without requiring the querystring value tagged on the end since there will be plenty of cases the image will need to be loaded in it's original form.  They will be in a format similar to somewebsite.com/images/{someid}/{somefilename}.ext.

This is a brand new website and I installed ImageResizer using the MVCWebConfig package in NuGet.  Right now I have the VirtualFolder plugin pointing to "~/testpath" and, like I said, ~/testpath/someimage.jpg doesn't work but ~/testpath/someimage.jpg?width=300 does.

I've gone through the troubleshooting, Stackoverflow, and Google searches and it seems like everything is set up correctly so I just don't understand why the built-in server works but IIS and IIS Express do not.

As a note, this is on Windows 7 Ultimate, VS2k12.  Express shows up as IIS8, regular IIS is 7.5.

Additionally, I have tried it with RAMMFAR (runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests) turned on and off.  *EDIT* -- I misreported that not having RAMMFAR was making the built-in server not render raw file, that is not the case.  RAMMFAR doesn't seem to affect it in either case but the use of vpp="true" was what made the difference.

*EDIT* Additionally, I have tried having the plugin use vpp="false" as well as vpp="true".

*EDIT 7/11/2013* Here is the resizer.debug diagnostic sheet details (running in IIS Express):

> Image resizer diagnostic sheet        7/11/2013 12:50:49 PM
>
> 2 Issues detected:
>
> (Warning):    To potentially see additional errors here, perform an image
>   resize request.
>
> (Warning):    NoCache is only for development usage, and cannot scale to
>   production use.           Add DiskCache or CloudFront for production use
>
> You are not using any paid bundles.
>
> Registered plugins:
>
> ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.DefaultEncoder
>   ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.NoCache
>   ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.ClientCache
>   ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.Diagnostic
>   ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.SizeLimiting
>   ImageResizer.Plugins.MvcRoutingShim.MvcRoutingShimPlugin
>   GAT.Web.Cdn.Plugins.ContentImagePlugin
>   ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.VirtualFolder
>   ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.Gradient
>
> Configuration:
>
> Accepted querystring keys:
>
> quality, format, thumbnail, color1, color2, angle, width, height,
>   maxwidth, maxheight, w, h, scale, stretch, crop, cropxunits,
>   cropyunits, page, bgcolor, rotate, flip, sourceFlip, sFlip, sRotate,
>   borderWidth, borderColor, paddingWidth, paddingColor, ignoreicc,
>   frame, useresizingpipeline, cache, process, margin, anchor, dpi, mode,
>   zoom,
>
> Accepted file extensions:
>
> bmp, gif, exif, png, tif, tiff, tff, jpg, jpeg, jpe, jif, jfif, jfi,
>
> Environment information:
>
> Running Microsoft-IIS/8.0 on Microsoft Windows NT 6.1.7601 Service
>   Pack 1 and CLR 4.0.30319.18052 Trust level: Unrestricted OS bitness:
>   x86 !! Warning, running as 32-bit on a 64-bit OS(AMD64). This will
>   limit ram usage !! Executing assembly: C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS
>   Express\iisexpress.exe IntegratedPipeline: True

Comment: We need the diagnostics page gist...

Comment: Added the diagnostics above; another thing I should note is that when I am running IIS or IIS Express in debug mode and attempt to access an "raw" file, it never drops into any of the methods on my custom plugin.  If I add the querystring it does.  I can only assume the exact same behavior is occurring with the VirtualFolder (the entire reason I added VirtualFolder to the project was because it acts as a decent template for my plugin).

Comment: We can't support custom plugins on SO without the source code. If this is happening with the stock version of VirtualFolder, that's different; but your diagnostics page is showing a custom plugin.

Comment: The VirtualFolder is there in the diagnostics, looks like it didn't catch the linebreak so it shows up at the end of the line with my custom plugin.  I am getting this behavior with the VirtualFolder plugin too.  I added the VirtualFolder plugin first so I could learn how it worked, and was modeling my code (to a very small degree) after the VirtualFolder because I realized I needed to inherit from the VirtualPathProvider instead of simply the IVirtualImageProvider in order to handle my use-case.  I'd be happy to provide the very simple and extremely incomplete code in my plugin.

Comment: Debugging requires the elimination of variables; it doesn't sound like this is a 'clean' project. Set up a new, empty one with just VirtualFolder and test.

Comment: I created a brand spankin new project, again, just added the VirtualFolder and nothing else and hosted in IIS express.  Still has the exact same behavior.  Switch it to the built-in webserver and it works.

Comment: With vpp="true" and RAMMFAR enabled?

Comment: Yes, vpp is true, RAMMFAR is enabled.  If I disable RAMMFAR but leave vpp true, it has the same behavior as above.

Comment: The same behavior as what?

Comment: Same behavior as always - that is, a "raw" image doesn't load in IIS Express or IIS but that "raw" image *does* load using the built-in webserver UNLESS I also include a querystring value, in which case, it works on all three server methods.  RAMMFAR doesn't make a difference one way or another in any of the three server use cases.